# "Safari" would like to control this computer using accessibility features

Tags: macos, safari, accessibility

I recently did a clean install of OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 on my MacBook Air.

I was making a credit card payment on the Barclaycard website and received a dialog window saying ""Safari" would like to control this computer using accessibility features."

I chose "Deny" but I am wondering why I received this dialog in the first place? I am certain I was on the actual, official Barclaycard website. Do I have malware? The only extensions I am using with Safari are AdBlock and 1Password.

[image]

Text only version:

> **"Safari" would like to control this computer using accessibility features.**
>
> Grant access to this application in Security & Privacy preferences, located in System Preferences.
>
> <kbd>Open System Preferences</kbd> <kbd>Deny</kbd>

Comment: Was it offering you to save your user name and password for that web site ?

Comment: If you open the Security & Privacy in the syst pref, then under Privacy tab, do you have Safari there and is it enabled?

Comment: @Buscar웃 It was not offering to save a username/password. It happened after I made my credit card payment and the credit card payment confirmation page loaded (Barclaycard Visa).

Comment: @Buscar웃 In System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility... Safari does appear but it is not enabled because I denied the request when it happened.

Comment: I just got this too, while visiting http://boingboing.net/2015/08/08/no-girl-wins-three-ways-women.html

Comment: I'd like to bump this question because I have the same question. Due to the fact that this appears to be dependent on requested functionality from some websites I am opting to not enable it for Safari. But I wonder very strongly what I might be missing out on.

Answer (score -4):

Based on the way accessibility features work in macOS, it is reasonable to assume that when saving or entering usernames and password using Apple's Keychain, or when using AutoFill to enter data into a page, that it uses some type of virtual keyboard that allows the system to enter text in user land. This would be very similar to how assistive devices function when using an Automator extension such as the "Watch Me Do" function. The reason why this comes up is because it is attempting to either read or write to the screen on behalf of the user.

This is an assumption, but it is based on working technical experience with the underlying software sets involved.

Comment: This can't be correct because AutoFill works even when accessibility to Safari is blocked.  Also, think about the security risk of running any confidential data through this many levels of software in an automated manner.  It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is possibly one of the most inaccurate, unsupported by facts, answers I have seen. Definitely worth the rep to down vote.